# Microsoft SQL Server users from OU/SG

Tags: active-directory, sql-server, organizational-unit, security-groups

MSSQL has its own user authentication apart from the operating system or Active Directory user authentication but can I apply database permissions to organisational units or security groups or somehow tie those to MSSQL?

Comment: You can certainly use Security Groups.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. At the SQL Server instance level, create a SQL Server [login for the AD group](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/authentication-access/create-a-login).
2. Add a [user](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/authentication-access/create-a-database-user) to the database.
3. (Optional, but good practice). Create a [database role](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/authentication-access/database-level-roles).
4. Link the [role to user](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/authentication-access/join-a-role).
5. Add [permissions](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/authentication-access/grant-a-permission-to-a-principal) to the role.